# Adding vue component to Laravel's main welcome.blade.php file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to add a header component to my main 'welcome.blade.php' file, but it's content is not rendering. What am I doing wrong here?

I have made my header component in my components folder like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="header">This is the header.</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
};
</script>
```

Then I imported my header to my main app.js file and registered my component like this:

```
import Header from './components/header';

Vue.component('header', Header);
```

Eventually I added my header tags to Laravel's main 'welcome.blade.php' file within the #app container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/evoqia-icon-gray.png') }}" />-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//creatio.com/themes/custom/creatio/favicon.ico" />
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
</head>

<body class="antialiased">
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
        <header></header>

        <div class="content-wrapper" :class="{'nopadding': !$store.state.authStore.user}">

            <div class="container app-container">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var Laravel = {
            'csrfToken': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        };
    </script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By _"not rendering"_ what do you see - nothing at all, an error message, the raw component code, something else?

Comment: Try renaming it, HTML already has a [<header>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) element

Comment: @Lissy93 I only saw the empty html tags in the code, no errors in my console

Comment: @brombeer, that did the trick. Now I renamed the component to 'page-header' it works